# My website displaying duplicate rows of records

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-9

I'm trying to make the 'My Mentors' and 'My Mentees' page to display records related to the logged in user and were able to do that.

MentorController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class MentorController extends Controller
{
  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    $user = $request->user();
    
    // $goals = DB::table('goal_mentors')
    //     ->join('users', 'goal_mentors.mentor_id', '=', 'users.id')
    //     ->join('goals', 'goal_mentors.goal_id', '=', 'goals.id')
    //     ->select('goals.user_id', 'goal_mentors.mentor_id', 'users.username', 'goal_mentors.goal_id', 'goals.id', 'goals.title', 'goals.description', 'goals.created_at')
    //     ->distinct()
    //     ->get();

    $goals = DB::table('goal_mentors')
        ->join('users', 'goal_mentors.mentor_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('goals', 'goal_mentors.goal_id', '=', 'goals.id')
        ->select('goals.user_id', 'goal_mentors.mentor_id', 'users.username', 'goal_mentors.goal_id', 'goals.id', 'goals.title', 'goals.description', 'goals.created_at')
        ->where('goals.user_id', "=", auth()->id())
        ->distinct()
        ->get();

    return view('my-mentors', ['user' => $user, 'goals' => $goals]);
   }
}
```

my-mentors.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'My Mentors')

@php
$highlighted_page = 'my_mentors';
@endphp

@section('content')
<main id="main" class="main">

<div class="pagetitle">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline" onclick="history.back()">
        <i class="bi bi-chevron-double-left"></i>
    </button>
    <h1>My Mentors</h1>
    <nav>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('home') }}">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">My Mentors</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
</div><!-- End Page Title -->

<section class="section dashboard">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- Left side columns -->
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">

                @foreach($goals as $goal1)
                @if(auth()->id() == $goal1->user_id)
                <!-- Goal Card -->
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">
                                <img src="{{ asset('/img/yor.jpg') }}" width="50" height="50" alt="Profile" class="mentor-mentee-profile-pic">
                                {{ $goal1->username }}
                            </h5>
                            <div class="list-group">
                                @foreach($goals as $goal2)
                                @if($goal1->mentor_id == $goal2->mentor_id)
                                <a href="goal-board-mentor.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                                    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                        <h5 class="list-title">{{ $goal2->title }}</h5>
                                        <small class="list-date text-muted">{{ $goal2->created_at }}</small>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="list-content">{{ $goal2->description }}</p>
                                </a>
                                @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- End Goal Card -->
                @endif
                @endforeach

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
</main>
@endsection
```

[Query Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc8Lw.png)

[How the website look like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoMt5.png)

Problem now is it iterating through all the output from the query using the loop and will print the same user with literally the same goals.

Comment: Don't put `Laravel` in the title; the tags accomplish that. Is there any reason you're not using Laravel Models? A `Goal` and `Mentor` (or `User`) model, with a relationship between them would make all of this much easier: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent, https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Yes, this should look like `auth()->user()->goals()->with("mentor")->get()` or similar. Very simple with correct relationships set up.

Comment: Your query results have two records with `mentor_id=40` for when you are looping over in the second (nested) foreach loop it will match twice for the record with `mentor_id=40` and you will get the user with `mentor_id=40` goals listed twice.

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure why do you start from middle table if you need to get goals with mentors for current user

```sql
select 
  *
from goals g
  join goal_mentors gm on g.id = gm.goal_id
  join users u on gm.mentor_id = u.id
where g.user_id = 51;
```

---

anyway, your case is classical [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relation between users(mentors) and goals

```php
//User model

  // these are user's goals
  public function goals(){
    return $this->hasMany(Goal::class);
  }

  // these are goals where user is mentor
  public function goalsAsMentor(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Goal::class, 'goal_mentors', 'mentor_id', 
  'goal_id');
  }

// Goal model

  // this is reverse for user's goals
  public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

  // these are mentors for goal
  public function mentors(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'goal_mentors', 'goal_id', 'mentor_id');
  }
```

now for user you can take goals with attached mentors

```php
// controller

/** @var User */
$user = auth()->user();

$goals = $user->goals()->with(['mentors'])->get();
return view('my-mentors', ['user' => $user, 'goals' => $goals]);

/*
result structure
array(
  [
    'id': 1,
    'title': '',
    'description': '',
    //other Goal fields
    mentors: [
      [
        'id': 1,
        'username': '',
        //other mentor(user) fields      
      ],
      // other mentors
    ]
  ],
  // other goals with same structure
)
*/
```

Comment: I'm actually new to laravel and all these eloquent concepts, but how do I call the attributes of the mentors such as the username in the views file? Since they are stored in a different table.

Answer (score -1):

Please check whether the following condition works.

```
@foreach($goals as $goal2)
 @if($goal1->mentor_id == $goal2->id)
```

Comment: nope, it only displays the list of users in their individual cards without the goals. basically a blank card. and yes, there are still duplicate mentors.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).